# Number of simple directed graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

How many simple directed graphs are there on the vertex set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$?

I know there are $2^\binom{n}{2}$ simple undirected graphs, but I am confused as to where to go on this problem. I believe that it is simply two times this answer because on each graph you now have to choose the direction.

Is this the correct way to think of this?

Comment: Well, if $S$ is the set of simple undirected graphs, the amount of simple directed graphs would be $\sum_{G\in S} 3^{|G|}$.  Don't know if that helps.

Comment: Tim, that's true, but "the amount of undirected graphs with exactly E edges and V vertices" is not such a pretty formula: ((V choose 2) choose E) (since you pick E of the (V choose 2) overall amount of possible edges)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's solve this the same way we solve it for undirected graphs:
For each pair of vertices (v,u) there are exactly four possibilities for the edges between them: either there is no edge between them, or just v->u, or just u->v, or both v->u and u->v.
so the answer would be 4 in the power of the amount of pairs of vertices, that is 4^(n choose 2).
Your idea was quite close, although you need to notice that the amount of ways to "choose 2 elements from a set of size N" is not 2N, but N^2. (which in our case gives the correct answer: (2^(n choose 2))^2 = 4^(n choose 2)  )

Comment: This works for labelled vertex graphs, but the graph isomorphism problem makes it quite difficult to count how many distinct (up to isomorphism) directed graphs there are on $n$ unlabelled vertices.

Comment: @hardmath Not really relevant because he was talking about labled ones.

Comment: I thought it could help a future reader to explicitly point out the labelled nature of the graphs being discussed (and how it affects the counting), and I slightly edited the Question to make its vertex notation clearer.  I upvoted your Answer BTW.

Comment: Thanks :)I'm just saying that both the question and the answer are very dependent on the fact the vertices are labeled. Questions regarding unlabeled vertices tend to be a lot tougher to answer, and a closed formula is often unknown/expressible through elementary functions.